# Python Convert data to pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to convert a data set with 100,000 rows and 3 columns into `pivot`. While the following code runs without an error, the values are displayed as `NaN`.

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df_TEST, values='actions', index=['sku'], columns=['user'])
```

It is not taking the values (ranges from 1 to 36 ) from `DataFrame`. Has anyone come across this situation?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I test it and it works very well with my sample `df_TEST = pd.DataFrame({'sku': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2}, 'user': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, 'actions': {0: 12, 1: 44, 2: 21}})
`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you are doing a pivot since not all the values might be present. e.g.

```
In [10]: df_TEST
Out[10]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  2  0
3  1  1  1
4  1  2  3
5  1  4  5
```

Now, when you do pivot on this,

```
In [9]: df_TEST.pivot_table(index='a', values='c', columns='b')
Out[9]: 
b   0  1  2   4
a              
0   0  0  0 NaN
1 NaN  1  3   5
```

Note that, you got NaN at index 0 and column 4, since there is no entry in df_TEST with column a = 0 and column b = 4.

Typically you fill such values with zeros.

```
In [11]: df_TEST.pivot_table(index='a', values='c', columns='b').fillna(0)
Out[11]: 
b  0  1  2  4
a            
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  3  5
```